# Recursive CTE with high scan count and logical reads

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, query-performance

I am trying to optimize below recursive CTE with no luck. The table is having 5079 records.

```
;WITH CTE_REC AS (

     SELECT         
          ID
        , ParentId
        , ID as ChildId
        , IsActive          
        FROM
        #temp

    UNION ALL


    SELECT 
         C.ID
        , C.ParentId    
        , H.ChildId 
        ,H.IsActive         
    FROM 
        #temp AS C
        INNER JOIN
        CTE_REC H ON C.ID = H.ParentId  
)
SELECT * FROM CTE_REC
```

Execution Plan for the above query is :

[image]

IO Statistics are :

```
(25441 row(s) affected)
Table 'Worktable'.
Scan count 20365, logical reads 193768, physical reads 0,
read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0,
lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table '#temp_______________________________________________________________________________________________________________000000001B2D'.
Scan count 2, logical reads 34, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 17,
lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
```

I have created below index on the temp table.

```
CREATE INDEX IX_TEMP ON #Temp(Id,ParentId)
```

After creating Index, Execution plan is like below.

[image]

IO Statistics after Index:

```
Table '#temp_______________________________________________________________________________________________________________000000001B2D'.
Scan count 20364, logical reads 40776, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0,
lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'Worktable'.
Scan count 2, logical reads 142778, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0,
lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
```

Still after Index there are high scan count and logical reads. The CTE returns 25411 rows and i didn't find any differences in CPU time which is 400 ms with / without Index.

Comment: You should reduce the number of rows of your anchor. Adding `WHERE ParentId IS NOT NULL` could be a good option, but it depends really on your data and what you need.

Comment: Why don't you use a `hierarchyid` instead of recursion?

Comment: I am not aware of hierarchyid. Could you give me any link regarding hierarchyid?

Comment: It appear that your query is wrong.Very high Cardianility estimate.you should improve your in Anchor and recursive both.

Comment: Odd formatting.

Comment: please provide test data to repro the ssue

Comment: What is the data type of the `ID` and `ParentId` columns?

Answer (score 0):

That recursion is just a lot of steps for the server.

I would just put a clustered PK on ID.

It may help to put a FK on ParentID to ID and it may hurt.

In the anchor you could put `where ParentId is not null` but there are not going to be many of them and it would eliminate them from the report.

In the anchor you could filter to only people that have no one reporting to them.  You still get all the chains.  It is kind of silly to have a separate chain on my boss when it is the same chain up as mine.

It is also wasteful to calculate the chain for piers.  If we have a common boss then we have the same chain.  Here 3 and 6 have the same chain. In my example below you only need to anchor on:

```
select min(e.id) as 'modelGrunt', e.mgr
  from @emp e  
 where not exists (select 1 from @emp e1 where e1.mgr = e.id)
 group by e.mgr;
```

From that information you can build every chain. Run that and materialize it. It is a more complex query but reduces the number of recursive rows to a near minimum.  It is not a full minimum as you could get crazy and not even repeat sub chains.

I have almost the same but at small counts it is not a problem.  You need to optimize with a sort as otherwise the result are not grouped in meaningful way.  This has an index seek and an index scan.

```
declare @emp table (id  int primary key, mgr int);  
insert into @emp values 
       (1, null)
     , (2, 1)
     , (3, 2)
     , (4, null)
     , (5, 4) 
     , (6, 2);
--select * from @emp;

; with cte as 
( select e.id ori, e.id, e.mgr, cnt = 1 
    from @emp e  
  union all 
  select cte.ori,  e.id, e.mgr, cnt + 1
    from @emp e 
    join cte 
      on cte.mgr = e.id 
) 

 select ori, id, mgr, cnt  
 from cte  
 order by ori, cnt;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your anchor isn't quite right, you need to restrict the top level to only rows that aren't child items:

```
;WITH CTE_REC AS (
     SELECT         
          ID
        , ParentId
        , ID as ChildId
        , IsActive          
        FROM #temp
        WHERE ParentId IS NULL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 
         C.ID
        , C.ParentId    
        , H.ChildId 
        ,H.IsActive         
    FROM #temp AS C
    INNER JOIN CTE_REC H 
       ON C.ID = H.ParentId  
    WHERE C.ParentId IS NOT NULL
)
SELECT * FROM CTE_REC
```

Comment: There are not many of them and they process quickly.   A problem is they are not reported directly.

Comment: @Paparazzi not sure I understand this comment. Please provide some sample data. The problem with not restricting the anchor to just the rows with null parentid is that you will report the same rows more than once. e.g. If A->B->C you will report this and B->C and C.

Comment: I don't agree.  I posted data in my answer.  If you add the null you propose you get a different report.  If you want to trim the chain this only trims the top of the chain.  I did not vote you down.  I think this is valid input.

Comment: @Paparazzi your join is not correct if you use this "on cte.id = e.mgr" as your join criteria, then you can add where .. not null to your anchor and then the anchors get reported correctly. In your query as it is, id 2 gets reported twice.

Comment: Not going to argue with you.  I have run the queries.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried creating a clustered index on the temp table. The index you have created is non-clustered, which means that your temp table will still be a heap, hence the high scan count, as the query will be scanning through the heap to do key lookups for ChildID, IsActive, etc.

Create a clustered index (CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX) on ID, ParentID on your temp table.
Then add a covering non-clustered index for ParentID, ID, ChildID, IsActive. You may need to test this NCI as it may be better to move ID to the end.

Comment: what did you cluster on? ID? Are you still using the NCI you created? try adding an NCI for ParentID, ID, ChildID, IsActive, instead of the one you described above

Comment: No. I removed NCI and created CI on ID, ParentID. No use.